# update a value column of a row based in another value of row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a historical table with data as bellow :

In my case the `product id` (110,111,112) had changed the `price` that way i have the same product with the value of the `product_updateDate` also sometimes i can have the same duplicate data with no information changed

```
+------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| id   | product_id | product_name | product_Price |       product_addDate       |   product_UpdateDate    |      Insertdate_DB      | Updatedate_DB  |
+------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|    1 |        110 |    DELL      |          1000 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
|    2 |        111 |    HP        |           900 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 3    |        112 |    Mac       |          1300 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 4    |        113 |   Lenovo     |           950 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 5    |        110 |   DELL       |           900 |    2017-03-04 08:00:00.000  | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 6    |        111 |    HP        |           800 |    2017-03-04 08:00:00.000  | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 7    |        112 |    Mac       |           120 |    2017-03-04 08:00:00.000  | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
+------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

What i want is doing an Update Query to get the result as bellow:

```
 +----+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| id | product_id | product_name | product_Price |     product_addDate     |   product_UpdateDate    |      Insertdate_DB      | Updatedate_DB |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|  1 |        110 | DELL         |          1000 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | GETDATE()     |
|  2 |        111 | HP           |           900 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | GETDATE()     |
|  3 |        112 | Mac          |          1300 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | GETDATE()     |
|  4 |        113 | Lenovo       |           950 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
|  5 |        110 | DELL         |           900 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
|  6 |        111 | HP           |           800 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
|  7 |        112 | Mac          |           120 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

The query as bellow can update the `product_UpdateDate`

```
update tablename 
set    product_UpdateDate = case when tablename.product_UpdateDate is null 
                                      then t.product_UpdateDate
                                      else null end
from   tablename 
join   tablename t 
on     tablename.product_id = t.product_id
and    t.ID <> tablename.id `
```

But also i want to change the `Updatedate_DB` with the `GETDATE()` value when i try to do update this column  all rows have the value `GETDATE()` but i want change only the rows that the value have change

Thanks for help

Comment: Hey, why you deleted your last question about slicing dates? I'm trying to resolve it.

Comment: @yoma just i was trying some test , the post is back

Answer (score 0):

I think `row_number()` might be a simpler method.  The logic is hard to follow, but the following should result in the data in your question:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by product_id) as cnt
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set product_UpdateDate = (case when seqnum = 1 then product_addDate end),
        Updatedate_DB = (case when seqnum = 1 then getdate() end)
    where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: thanks for reply it's work but one problem is when i execute the query another time the `Updatedate_DB` change the information i my case i don't want change the `Updatedate_DB`  even if i execute the query more than one time because i will use the query in `SSIS Package`

Comment: @Mark . . . That sounds like a requirement that is not part of this question.  Perhaps you should ask another question, with suitable data and desired results.